# Guardar urls en un array

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, variables, arraylist

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
   getMarkerMapGuideUrl(markersPrincipal) {
        var _this = this;
        for(var i = 0; i < markersPrincipal.length; i++) {
            var markerElement = markersPrincipal[i];

            var urlImagesMarkers = 'images/guides/markers/';
            var extensionImagesMarkers ='.png';
            var urlMarkers= this.getMarkerPrincipalImage(markerElement);
    
            return urlImagesMarkers + urlMarkers + extensionImagesMarkers;
        }
    }
```

y necesito guardar en una variable las diferentes url que arroja la funcion pero me esta generando solo la primera, y un console.log en la funcion en la variable markerElement ya me esta devolviendo solo el primer resultado de un array que tiene un length de 56 elementos, y si lo haces al markersPrincipal si devuelve los 56 elementos.

Que podria estar fallando en la funcion?

La variable que llama la funcion seria asi:

```
markerGuidesImage = _this.getMarkerMapGuideUrl(markersPrincipal);
```

Comment: Por favor indica que lenguaje estas utilizando, parece js, pero bien podría no serlo, para dar respuestas mas precisas es importante esa información, para hacer pruebas y darte un ejemplo funcional.
Ahora yendo al código el problema es que estas retornando dentro del for, los return no son acumulativos, por lo que al aparecer el primero la función se cierra devolviendo el valor correspondiente, así que tendrías que armar un array e ir añadiendo información dentro del for, una vez fuera del for usar un return con el array completo.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, no es necesario que tengas tus variables `urlImagesMarkers` y `extensionImagesMarkers` dentro del `for`, estos hay que llevarlos afuera:

```
getMarkerMapGuideUrl(markersPrincipal) {
  var _this = this;
  var urlImagesMarkers = 'images/guides/markers/';
  var extensionImagesMarkers = '.png';

  for (var i = 0; i < markersPrincipal.length; i++) {
    var markerElement = markersPrincipal[i];

    var urlMarkers = this.getMarkerPrincipalImage(markerElement);

    return urlImagesMarkers + urlMarkers + extensionImagesMarkers;
  }
}
```

Luego, puedes crear un array vacío para almacenar tus URL, y en cada ciclo del `for`, pusheas el `markerElement` que obtienes en cada ciclo junto con las variables que movimos arriba, y al final retornas ese array, quedando así:

```
getMarkerMapGuideUrl(markersPrincipal) {
  var _this = this;
  var urlImagesMarkers = 'images/guides/markers/';
  var extensionImagesMarkers = '.png';
  var urls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < markersPrincipal.length; i++) {
    var markerElement = markersPrincipal[i];

    var urlMarkers = this.getMarkerPrincipalImage(markerElement);

    urls.push(urlImagesMarkers + urlMarker + extensionImagesMarkers);
  }

 return urls;
}
```